# size(X, 1) must be greater than n_components and n_components must be greater than 1

Tags: matrix, julia

I got a 2*86 matrix. And I want to apply umap on this matrix in Julia. So my code is

```
embedding = umap(matrix; n_neighbors=2, min_dist=0.1, n_epochs=200)
```

While I got the error "ArgumentError: size(X, 1) must be greater than n_components and n_components must be greater than 1" How to solve this error?

Answer (score 4):

If you have an n×m matrix, UMAP.jl interprets it as m observations of n-dimmensional data, i.e. every column in your input is a vector in your input space. Since `umap` reduces the dimensionality of your data the number of rows in your input needs to be larger than than the requested number of output components, `n_components` which defaults to 2 and can't (at this moment) be 1 in UMAP.jl.

You have 86 observations of 2-dimensional data. Since the data is already 2-dimensional you can't use `umap` to reduce the dimensionality.

Comment: Thx! If I have a higher dimensional matrix right now, and I want to define the dimensions I want. Is there a way to do that in Julia? For example, I want to get a 3-dimension result rather than 2 in Julia.

Comment: Look at MultivariateStats and its fit(PCA, matrix; maxoutdim=x) type statements, they allow arbitrary output dimensions AFAIK

Comment: @JosieG you can give the number of output dimensions as the second argument to the umap function. Adapting the code in your question: `embedding = umap(matrix, 3; n_neighbors=2, min_dist=0.1, n_epochs=200)`